# admin content overridden view not displaying

Tags: views, 6

I have updated Drupal 6 using drush and all my admin views stopped working.
I create a new view but when I display it the server takes too long with no response. I tried to track error log to see if something is wrong but the only error I got was php timeout error.

note: the main view node under admin/content/node is working fine and display all the content as usual. but all other views like admin/content/node2 not displaying at all.

What may cause this?